# Timestamp issue in swift3 using firebase

Tags: swift

When I add a new feedback I send timestamp with that and it’s added successfully in db.After adding when I hit the service I get all the feedback including newly added feedback  with timestamp and when I parse all these data then newly added feedback timestamp is not getting into if condition

```
if (dictionary["timestamp"] as? u_long) != nil {
        feedbackTimestamp = (dictionary["timestamp"] as? u_long)!
}
else{
        feedbackTimestamp = 0
}
```

It goes into else and become 0 but all other feedback timestamp is getting into if condition. One thing more the new ly added feedback goes into if condition wen I quit the app and launch again. Here is my response from server.

```
(lldb) po print(dictionary)
["uniqueCode": IVIVC578OL5PH, "status": Pending Approval, 
"name": Test, "desc": Vjdjxjdbfcj, "id": feedback20170419_032044, 
"title": bidh, "timestamp": 1492586444448, "category": water, 
"uid": mGs1zKSblyLyZALNtKw8YiGEr962, 
"url": https://imageurl/o/images%2Ffeedback%2Ffeedback20170419_032041?alt=media&token=6f4e2d2b-2ced-4cf2-b8ad-07375fdae0d8]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply a cast to `Double`

```
feedbackTimestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Double ?? 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply a cast to `Int`.

The expression can be reduced to one line with the nil-coalescing operator:

```
feedbackTimestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Int ?? 0
```

and if `feedbackTimestamp` is required to be `u_long`

```
feedbackTimestamp = u_long(dictionary["timestamp"] as? Int ?? 0)
```

However I'd use the higher level type `UInt` rather than `u_long`